# Subscribe to a group of users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

How to subscribe to a group for calendar events in Microsoft Graph API?

We have around 20,000 users and we need to subscribe to each users calendar event.

Is there a way to subscribe to AD group instead of individual users?

Most of examples shows subscription for a single user:

```
/v1.0/subscriptions/me/events
/v1.0/subscriptions/users/test@testemail.com/events)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions are per-calendar, there isn't a subscription model available for multiple multiple calendars across multiple users.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Marc!! i will post for this change in UserVoice.